# should I use an empy div for a link to facebook?

Tags: css, header, icons, z-index

My header is a quite big image made in photoshop. I want to place some small custom icons with facebook, twitter, youtube etc. on this header in various places (left, right, top, middle). I want these icons to have a link to my fb, youtube page.

I am not sure what is the best approach. Should I put these icons on my header in photoshop and then with an empty div should I try to find the exact position of the icon and link it to my fb page? Or should I put the icon in my div and with z-index in css to position it on top of my header?

Another solution? I've surfed the net for hours and couldn't find anything..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would position the icons on top of the header so I could change them later.  Simply surround the image with an anchor and put them inside of a `div`.  Move them into your exact position with CSS.

```
<div style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">
    <a href="http://facebook.com">
        <img src="facebook-icon.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

If you insist upon integrating the icons into your graphical design as you describe, then the best way to link them would be to use "image maps".  It achieves a similar effect as, yet makes far more sense than, placing a transparent clickable `div` over them.

```
<map name="myImageMap"> 
    <area shape="rect" coords="14,45,202,94" href="location-1.html">
    <area shape="circle" coords="396,62,48" href="location-2.html">
</map>

<img src="myImage.jpg" width="1200" height="200" usemap="#myImageMap" />
```

http://graphicdesign.spokanefalls.edu/tutorials/tech/imagemapexample/imagemap.htm

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is best to use `<a>` tags with the `background-image` property set to whatever the icon is. Position these over top of your header image. If you create the icons in the same image as your header, it may give you problems later. Doing it separately allows you to move them around or change the icons without having to edit the entire header image.

Comment: What's wrong with an actual `<img>`? Something that you're supposed to interact with is by definition not a background image.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear. The OP has custom icons for multiple services (FB, Twitter, Youtube, etc...). It is better to combine all of these icons into one background-image and use `background-position` to make each icon visible for it's respective link. Read here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that, if there is no text to go with the icon, it should be an image (using `<img>`), **not** a background-image because it is the only visual means of interacting with the link. This also has accessibility implications.

Comment: `<img />` is not used for interaction, `<a />` is. With `<img />` you have less CSS code, but with `background-image` you have some slight performance benefits, and it makes it just a _little_ harder to get a URL to an image. `<img />` also has potential to break the layout if images are disabled, then again you just have empty blocks without it with `<a />`. There's no real right way, and you can achieve the same exact interface with either-or. However `background-image` _seems_ to be more widely used by professionals than the `<img />` tag.

Comment: @andrewjackson If there is no text in the `<a>` then there is *nothing* to interact with, so there should be an `<img>` rather than a `background-image`. If there *is* text in the `<a>` (e.g. "Facebook") then the image can be regarded as nothing more than graphical fluff, and can be a `background-image`. You should **never** sacrifice proper semantics and accessibility for a slight performance boost. (As an example, look at the social networking icons on SO under the question up/downvote links)

Comment: That's just plain not how the DOM works. Text and contents of an _anchor_ are simply **properties** of an _anchor_ **object**. You interact with the _anchor_ object itself. I think what is confusing you is the fact that an _anchor_ isn't normally a _block_. Logan failed to mention that, but I have in my answer. An empty _anchor_ will not appear without a _width_ and _height_ set, which means it's `display` should be set as a `block` as well. The text for the icons on this site are fail-safes for when images are disabled.

Comment: I think Andrew understands how the DOM works. He is just saying that it isn't 'proper'. What is proper can be interpreted in many different ways. Both methods in this case have pros and cons. Either way, the idea of positioning the element over the header image remains the same.

Comment: There's is absolutely _nothing_ in the W3C standards that states it is improper to leave an _anchor_ with no _text_ or _html_ **properties**.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real right answer to this, since there's literally many ways to do this, but if you're just asking for an opinion to keep it simple, this is what I would do. However, that does not mean it is the best thing to do.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .header { position:absolute; height:200px; width:700px; } /*change width/height to actual size*/
    a.link { background-image:url(t.png); display:block; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:1; }
    a.icon { display:block; position:absolute; top:50px; height:32px; width:32px; z-index:2; } /*assuming icons are same size*/
    a.fb { background-image:url(b.png); right:94px; } /* 3 10px spacers plus 2 icons widths */ 
    a.tw { background-image:url(a.png); right:52px; } /* 2 10px spacers plus 1 icon width */
    a.yt { background-image:url(r.png); right:10px; } /* 1 10px spacer */
</style>

<div class="header">
    <a class="header link" href="#"></a>
    <a class="icon fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>
    <a class="icon tw" href="http://www.twitter.com/"></a>
    <a class="icon yt" href="http://www.youtube.com/"></a>
</div>
```

If you're going to take the anchor background image approach, you're going to need to set the anchor to a block, and then set the dimensions of that block, as seen in the example.

A nice trick is to combine all of your icons into a single image, that way you only need to load one image, so there's less header calls. You then use the `background-position` CSS property to re-position the background image for each icon. For this example, we assume you have three 32x32 icons, which would make one 96x32 image.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .header { position:absolute; height:200px; width:700px; } /*change width/height to actual size*/
    a.link { background-image:url(t.png); display:block; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:1; }
    a.icon { background-image:url(x.png); display:block; position:absolute; top:50px; height:32px; width:32px; z-index:2; } /*assuming icons are same size*/
    a.fb { background-position:0px 0px; right:94px; } /* 3 10px spacers plus 2 icons widths */ 
    a.tw { background-position:-32px 0px; right:52px; } /* 2 10px spacers plus 1 icon width */
    a.yt { background-position:-64px 0px; right:10px; } /* 1 10px spacer */
</style>

<div class="header">
    <a class="header link" href="#"></a>
    <a class="icon fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>
    <a class="icon tw" href="http://www.tweeter.com/"></a>
    <a class="icon yt" href="http://www.youtube.com/"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see my [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245637/should-i-use-an-empy-div-for-a-link-to-facebook/9245658#comment11648074_9245658) on [Logan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9245658/211563).

Comment: I added an example for that as well.

Comment: How? I don't see such an example anywhere in your answer.

Comment: Actually, to be completely honest... I have absolutely no clue what you are talking about whatsoever, if I have still failed to explain your own question.